# How can I validate that a variable amount of Ajax forms have been completed from an outside html form?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, validation

NOTE FOR CLARITY:  The sibling HTML form is used to advance to the next page.  The separate Ajax forms need to independently validate data.  The outside (to the ajax forms) HTML form needs to be able to validate that ALL of the ajax forms have been completed before advancing to the next web page.

I have a variable amount of Ajax forms and an HTML form on the same web page.  The HTML form is a sibling of the ajax forms since nesting ajax forms within an html form doesn't work.  I'm able to validate within each of the ajax forms and the HTML form, but what I'm trying to do is validate that ALL of those ajax forms are filled out from the outside HTML form.  How would I be able to accomplish this with JQuery?  I'd like to be able to tie the overall validation of all forms (ajax and html) to the button for the HTML form.  I'd appreciate the advice and possibly some example code.  Also, I would appreciate links to any plugins that might be required.  Thanks!

Comment: If you want to validate various ajax forms" and a HTML form together on the HTML submit button, would it not be more appropriate to rather have one Ajax submitted form? 
There are JQuery validation plugins available, but they probably wont work if you have multiple forms trying to work as one.
Perhaps you can give a code example of the relation between the forms. This could help define a solution.

Comment: The ajax forms need to be separate because they are different sets of data (depending on what is pulled out of the database) and they each need to be validated independently.  The overall HTML form is a separate sibling that is used to advance to the next webpage once all of the ajax forms have been validated.

Comment: All the forms need to be validated before you can continue and you have one submit button that "submits" all the data? You basically have one large form and you should handle all of them with one submission function. I suggest you basically do as @slayergirl answered. And you do not need a HTML form to progress to a next page.

Answer (score 0):

$('#field-name').val() and there's also a .find() and such if that isn't good enough. you can also just set an event handler on each element and $(this).val() stuff. hth

Answer (score 0):

Can't you write your own submit function?

```
     $('#some_form').on('submit', function(event){
        event.preventDefault()

     //make an array of data in fields per form (each form needs an unique id)
     var data = $('#some_form').serializeArray();
     var other_data = $('#other_form').serializeArray();


      //you can now loop through each field
           $.each(data, function(id, post_data) {
                //should check your data here
                console.log (post_data.name);
                console.log (post_data.value);
         });

        //you can now loop through each field
           $.each(other_data, function(id, post_data) {
                //should check your data here
                console.log (post_data.name);
                console.log (post_data.value);
         });


      //everything right? ok do what you need to do. Show another page, save data 
    }
```

Comment: That sounds like an interesting idea, but how would you handle the case if you don't know the exact id of the various forms since there is a variable number of forms depending on the data pulled from the database?

Comment: You could give a css class attribute to the forms. Then you can use JQuery to get the inputs of any form with the specific CSS attribute.

Comment: `var arr_form = $("form");
            $.each (arr_form, function (key, form) {
                console.log (form.id);
            });`

this fetches id's of forms used on the page